# How to change file types in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-colab

I have 2 files in My Drive with `ipynb` extension.
One is marked as `Unknown file` type and has a blue icon, and the other is marked as `Colaboratory` type.

How do I change both to be `Colaboratory`?

[image: one_file_unknown_one_colab]

Answer (score 0):

An identical question has been asked on StackOverflow - [.ipynb file in Google Drive doesn't open with Colaboratory by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62649413/1330560). The accepted answer by @JeffRush can be summarised as follows:

> "If you want to get that icon you should save a copy from Colab"

His detailed answer includes an explanation of the steps to do this.